# Loading a class and static block

Tags: java

I am currently learning java and am a beginner in it. I am very confused with what does it mean for a class to be loaded and especially if there is a static block in the class called Locations. This is part of a source code that i have encountered in a course.

```
public class Locations implements Map<Integer, Location> {
    private static Map<Integer,Location> locations = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileWriter file = null;
        try{
            file= new FileWriter("locations.txt");
            for(Location location : locations.values()){
                file.write(location.getLocationID()+ ", "  +location.getDescription() + "\n");
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            System.out.println("In catch block");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            try{
            if(file!=null){
                System.out.println("Attempting to close file");
                file.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
    }

    static{
        locations.put(0, new Location(0, "You are sitting in front of a computer learning Java",null));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should read about class initialization sequence in java. For a class it's static block, static variable, instance block , instance variable then constructor get loaded in memory. If class has any parent then it's get prefered. Just play around by creating sample class and observe things.

Answer (score 0):

Class loaders are responsible for **loading Java classes during runtime dynamically to the JVM** (Java Virtual Machine).

Java classes aren't loaded into memory all at once, but when required by an application. Class loader for loading classes into memory.

NOTE: Nice tutorial given by Oracle [links](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/classloaders.html)